# Activerecord association extensions on belongs_to

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Is it possible to do an association extension on a `belongs_to` relation?

I have tried to do it using a module but keep being told that the method I'm calling is private:

```
module TestExtension
  def test
    puts 'test successful'
  end
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, extend: TestExtension
end
```

Every time I run it though it complains that the method is private

```
q = Question.first
q.test
# => NoMethodError: Attempt to call private method `test'
```

I'm not 100% clear whether it's possible to do AR Extensions on belongs_to. It was working fine on Rails 3.0.7 but is now failing in 3.1.0

Comment: where do you put the module TestExtension? In a new file in the lib directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://gist.github.com/rails/rails/issues/2117) in 3.1.0 that hasn't been resolved yet. Basically, the new association design in 3.1.0 doesn't support extending `belongs_to` associations since it was never a supported feature in the first place. However, the issue is still open so it may be resolved in the future; you should probably comment on the issue to voice support if you want it.

Also, the private method error you're getting, you would be getting even if you didn't have the `extend: TestExtension` part; I believe `#test` is a private method on all `ActiveRecord` objects.

Comment: Very helpful - thanks for the heads up on both points. I had no idea about the .test restriction